# Change IAP price

Tags: ios-appstore, mac-appstore, in-app-purchase

I'm planning on increasing the prices of my Non-Consumable IAPs.

My question is, will existing users who already purchased those IAPs be affected? As in, will it still count as "purchased" ? The only thing that will change is the price. The IAPs will have the same Product ID.

I absolutely do not want them to have to purchase it again at a higher price.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Non-consumable IAPs are only ever purchased once. Changing the price will not affect existing purchases.